# How can I INSERT data and DELETE duplicate rows using a single SQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to Insert data into a table at the same time deleting if there is any duplicate entry exist in the table. There is a way of storing duplicated data identifiers into a temp table and then deleting them. But it is not an efficient way to do so. Any better idea will be appreciated.

**MY TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE account(  
  user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,  
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,  
  password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,  
  email VARCHAR(355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,  
  created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
  last_login TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Comment: You can't insert and delete in a single SQL statement.  But, you can do it within a single logical transaction.

Comment: Why not do an "upsert" instead? If the row is there, then update it with the new values instead of deleting it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you _can_ insert and delete in a single statement using [data modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How do you know so much about Postgres?  Why is Postgres so different from other RDBMS?  Why do I spend so much time on this site?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can we do it using row count?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "why is it different" - because it's the most advanced open source database ;)

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me  what exactly you want to achieve. I think it would be easier if you can supply some sample data and the expected outcome for what you want to do. Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below your question) do not post additional information in comments. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3):

The "immediate" answer would be to simply run DELETE statement, then run the INSERT statement in a single transaction.

Assuming you want e.g. avoid duplicate usernames, then you could do something like this:

```
begin transaction
  delete from account
  where username = 'arthur';

  insert into account(username, password, email, created_on)
  values ('arthur', '****', 'arthur@h2g2.com', current_timestamp);
commit;
```

You *can* combine that into a single statement, but it doesn't make a big difference:

```
with new_values (username, password, email, created_on) as (
  values values ('arthur', '****', 'arthur@h2g2.com', current_timestamp);
), deleted as (
  delete from the_table 
  where username = (select username from new_values)
) 
insert into account
select *
from new_values;
```

The only advantage here is that you don't need to repeat the values twice.

However, if the `account` is referenced by other tables (i.e. foreign key "pointing" to `the_table`) then this is not going to work as the DELETE will fail if the row is still referenced.

The better solution is to use `INSERT ON CONFLICT` and then update the existing row with the new data:

```
insert into account(username, password, email, created_on)
values ('arthur', '****', 'arthur@h2g2.com', current_timestamp)
on conflict (username) 
do update 
  set password = excluded.password, 
      email = excluded.email;
```

This would however still throw an error if the email already exists, but unfortunately for an `on conflict do update` you can only specify **one** unique constraint.

To deal with two different unique constraints, things get a bit more complicated:

```
with new_values (username, password, email, created_on) as (
  values 
    ('arthur', '***', 'arthur@h2g2.com', current_timestamp)
), inserted as (
  insert into account(username, password, email, created_on)
  select * from new_values
  on conflict do nothing
  returning id
)
update account
  set password = nv.password
from new_values nv  
where (account.username = nv.username or account.email = nv.email)
  and not exists (select * from inserted);
```

First an insert attempt is made. If that any unique constraint is violated, the insert is simply ignored (`on conflict do nothing`).

The final UPDATE statement is only executed if no row was inserted from the previous step. That is achieved through the `and not exists (select * from inserted`.

As either the username *or* the email could have caused the constraint violation, the update uses an or condition on those two columns to update the existing row. If you want, you could also update more columns in there.

Answer (score -3):

I think a really easy way to do this is to add a UNIQUE index on the specific columns. When you write the ALTER statement, include the IGNORE keyword. Like so:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE orders ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1, col2, col3, others);
```

This will drop all the duplicate rows. As an added benefit, future INSERTs that are duplicates will error out. As always, you may want to take a backup before running something like this...

I hope this can help you.

Comment: That is not valid for Postgres